# Associated types and generics on protocols

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm trying to declare a function in a protocol that forces types that conform to it to return a value of that same protocol but with a specific associated type:

```
protocol Protocol {
    typealias ValueType

    var value : ValueType? {get}

    func getProtocolString<A where A : Protocol, A.ValueType == String>() -> A
}
```

This compiles. It's when I try to create a class that conforms to it that I get the errors:

```
class AClass<T> : Protocol {
    var value : T?       

    func getProtocolString<A where A : Protocol, A.ValueType == String>() -> A {
        return AClass<String>()
    }
}
```

The error is *'AClass' is not convertible to 'A'*.

Am I missing something? Is this even possible?

Thank you

Comment: You declare a protocol having a _generic_ type `ValueType`. Then, in order to conform to the protocol itself, one must have `ValueType == String`. Thus `ValueType` is not intended to be _generic_. Notice that `String` is not a protocol, but a concrete type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with confusing a generic placeholder constrained by a protocol, with the protocol itself.  Here’s a simpler example, similar to your code, to try and make it clear:

```
// first, define a protocol and two structs that conform to it
protocol P { }
struct S1: P { }
struct S2: P { }

// now, a function that returns an object in the form
// of a reference to protocol P
func f() -> P {
    // S1 conforms to P so that’s fine 
    return S1()
}
// ok all well and good, this works fine:
let obj = f()

// now, to do something similar to your example code,
// declare a generic function that returns a generic
// placeholder that is _constrained_ by P
// This will NOT compile:
func g<T: P>() -> T { return S1() }
```

Why does this not compile?

The way generic functions work is that *at compile time*, when you call the function, the compiler decides what type the placeholder `T` needs to be, and then writes you a function with all occurrences of `T` replaced with that type.

So with the example below, `T` should be replaced by `S1`:

```
let obj1: S1 = g()
// because T needs to be S1, the generic function g above is 
// rewritten by the compiler like this:
func g() -> S1 { return S1() }
```

This looks OK.  Except, what if we wanted `T` to be `S2`?  `S2` conforms to `P` so is a perfectly legitimate value for `T`.  But how could this work:

```
// require our result to be of type S2
let obj2: S2 = g()
// so T gets replaced with S2… but now we see the problem.
// you can’t return S1 from a function that has a return type of S2.
// this would result in a compilation error that S2 is not
// convertible to S1
func g() -> S2 { return S1() }
```

Here is the origin of the error message you are getting.  Your placeholder `A` can stand in for any type that conforms to `Protocol`, but you are trying to return a *specific* type (`AClass`) that conforms to that protocol.  So it won’t let you do it.

Comment: Perfect answer, really well explained. I was missing the fact that function generics work at compile time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are a little misunderstanding generics. Generic functions are instantiated at call sites of these, not at each function itself body. So, the type constraints you've  written are saying that this function returns a value, a type of which may be any of all the subtypes of the `Protocol`. Consequently, the function definition must be statically correct about `A` for all the subtypes of `Protocol`, not only for `AClass<String>`, which is only an one type of `Protocol`.

In any case, I think there is no direct way to achieve what you want, at least in current Swift.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work in the playground... does it work for what you are trying to do?

```
protocol StringProtocol
{
    typealias ValueType

    var value : ValueType? { get }

    func getProtocolString<A where A: StringProtocol, A.ValueType == String>() -> A
}

class StringClass : StringProtocol
{
    typealias ValueType = String

    var value : ValueType?

    init() { }

    func getProtocolString<A where A: StringProtocol, A.ValueType == String>() -> A
    {
        return StringClass() as A
    }
}
```

I'm still not exactly following what requirements you are trying to fulfill with this implementation.